# adding users to answers_watchers table from comment.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following code in my Answer.rb model of my Rails app. After a user has posted an answer (to a question), they get added to a list to be notified if a comment is posted on the answer.

Answer.rb

```
 has_and_belongs_to_many :watchers, :join_table => "answer_watchers", :class_name => "User"

after_create :creator_watches_me
  private 

  def creator_watches_me
    self.watchers << user
  end
```

This (together with code not shown) works to notify the user who answered the question if a comment is posted. However, if that same user posts a comment in reply, I want the original commenter to be notified if a comment is added by the answerer or anyone else. Therefore, I want to add anyone who makes a comment on an answer to this same list--but separate lists should be kept for each instance of an answer obviously. Here's where I'm running into trouble.

I'm assuming it (the new commenter) has to be added to the answer instance rather than the class, although I'm not entirely sure how to do that.  The code below is all broken. I'm just trying to play around with how it might work without success.

In my comment.rb model, I added this code that would pass the user to a method add_to_watchers in the Answer model

comment.rb

```
 after_create :creator_watches_me
      private 

  def creator_watches_me
    Answer.add_to_watchers(user)
  end
```

and in the Answer.rb model, I had this

```
  def add_to_watchers(user)
    self.watchers << user
  end
```

but now I can't add a comment at all. I get this error

```
undefined method `add_to_watchers' for #<Class:0x007faead33f7f8>
```

One problem I'm guessing I might be having is I don't know how to refer to the instance of the Answer from the comment model and how to pass that instance to Answer.rb so it knows which answer the user should be added to. That could be totally wrong of course :( I've read a few blog posts on instance and class methods but I'm having trouble getting it sorted out in my code, if that's even the issue I'm having.

So you know, there is an association between Answer and Comment.  Answer.rb has_many :comments.

Comment: @fmendez I think `add_to_watchers` needs to be an instance method because it refers to the `watchers` instance method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I think you worked out you are calling `add_to_watchers` on the `Answer` class rather than the related Answer instance and that method is not implemented by the `Class` class. So thats why you get the error.

I am guessing you have an association from Comment to Answer like:

```
belongs_to :answer
```

In that case you can refer to the related Answer instance with `answer` so try:

```
def creator_watches_me
  answer.add_to_watchers(user)
end
```

Comment: I didn't realize I could just call 'answer' from the comment model if the association was defined. thanks

Comment: Yes the Active Record association helpers like `has_many` and `belongs_to` generate methods like `comments`, `answer` and `answer=`.